# how to send POST request and get back response without the page loads with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I want to send a post request to my NodeJS server to update a document in my database and get back the response, but I don't want the page loads, I just want to alert it that the process has been successfully done
.....
here is my code
HTML:

```
 <form action="/products/update" method="POST" id="myFrom">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">save</button>

    <input type="number" name="productCount">

    <input type="text" name="productName">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#myFrom").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    });
});
```

NodeJS:

```
router.post("/products/update", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).send("success");
});
```

the poblem is when i press save it redirects to `/products/update` and types success in it, but i want the success to be an alert in the editing page

Comment: The button is a "submit" button, so it submits the form. Make it `type=button` instead.

Comment: then how to submit the form?

Comment: Your very own function contains an ajax request already. Just make it a "click" handler on  the button. You really don't need the `<form>` at all.

Comment: can you please show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User e.preventDefault() to submit form without refreshing the page

```
 $("#myFrom").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
  });
 });
```

Comment: @fkushgvosvu your `$.ajax()` call is missing some things, like the URL and the POST parameters.

Comment: they are on the form action and method

Comment: what @Pointy is saying you need to include URL and method when making an ajax call, its slightly different from html form submit, while making ajax request you're making a fresh request.